# AIDE and Eclipse Project Error

Tags: android, xml, target

I created an Android project in AIDE on my android phone running ICS and then to create an APK i copied the project folder into my PC and when i opened it in Eclipse, i get the following error:

***[2012-03-28 09:04:04 - ColorFinder] Unable to resolve target 'android-10'***

my AndroidManifext.xml looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sikni8.colorfinder"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk 
        android:minSdkVersion="8" 
        android:targetSdkVersion="11" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

How do i find out what are the minimum and maximum target created by AIDE?
In my PC i only installed ***Android 4.0.3 (API 15).*** Can that be the reason?
Thanks

***EDIT:***
I have a few OnClickListener for buttons, but during compilation all four are giving me the following error: "The type OnClickListener is ambiguous"
An example:

```
        clearValButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                //@Override
                public void onClick(View z) {
                    hMain.setEnabled(true);
                    rMain.setEnabled(true);
                    gMain.setEnabled(true);
                    bMain.setEnabled(true);
                    findViewById(R.id.dummyFocus).setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                    findViewById(R.id.dummyFocus).requestFocus();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "All inputboxes are now Enabled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}});
```

Comment: yes it is an issue with the sdk download.

Comment: I re-downloaded it twice now :(
Everything is working except the onClickListener... i provided an example from my app above and the error I get when i compile, any idea blackbelt? Thanks

Comment: Try `new View.OnClickListener()`

Comment: the View.onClickListener() took all the error away after i commented out the @Override... Thanks guys!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You nearly gave the answer yourself:

```
Unable to resolve target 'android-10'
```

and

```
In my PC i only installed Android 4.0.3 (API 15)
```

So the Project requires Android 10, but you only got 15 installed.
So what stops you from installing the Android level 10 (2.3.3) with the Android SDK Manager or change the Build Target to 15?

Comment: So instead of 11 should i change to 15? or just download 10 as well, but question is why its looking for target 10 when the target is 11?
I was confused because although it says SDKTarget is 11, i coded the app in ICS which is 15 and it worked just fine...

Comment: There is a huge difference. Basically the targetSDKVersion tells Android to not or to Activiate the Compatibility Mode (it doesn't matter if the level is available on your PC). But the Build Target is set in Project Properties - Android and tells Eclipse with which Version the Project is to build.- That is what you have to change or download.

Comment: After I installed all of the required APIs, now I get a compilation error. But in AIDE everything worked just fine and I was able to compile and run the app and installed and worked just fine...

Comment: TL;DR version: Change the "target" value in `project.properties` of your Android project to the corresponding value. For example: if your target value is `android-10`, and you only have Android 4.0.3 API installed, set the value to `android-15`. Eclipse will automatically fix the libraries for you.